# Loading contents of PHP file with AJAX script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to load the contents of a php file into a script using AJAX with the following code:

```
<button onclick="changeText3()"><img border='0' alt='More Options' src='tmpls/media/images/icons/cog.png'></button>
<script> function changeText3(){
   $("#test").click(function(){
   $("#test").load("file.php");
    }
}
</script>
<div id='test'>test</div>
```

Nothing happens when I click anything. I'm brand new to AJAX and am likely missing something simple. I've tried a number of different methods I've seen and I've had no luck.

Comment: Check the console tab in firebug. It will definitely show some error or output.

Comment: "nothing happens" - did you check in the **developer** tools console?

Comment: $("#test").click() - Why?

Comment: ooh, that would mean you have to click on an empty div (good luck finding it) to actually do the "load" part - well picked up @Webbanditten

Comment: @Naveed Ramzan There is an error saying changeText3 is not defined.

Comment: You don' need $("#test").click(function(){} event listener, just remove it

Comment: Well its not the correct logic that you are calling a function on click and again click event on Text. 
Let me add an answer

Comment: @Arthur Walker show your full code have you include jQuery file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button id="showOutput">
    <img border='0' alt='More Options' src='tmpls/media/images/icons/cog.png'>
</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showOutput").click(function(){
            $("#test").load("file.php");
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='test'>test</div>
```

Here we can see that as you tried JQuery so I removed JS function and catch JQuery event.

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More]".

Comment: Also, if I change it to $("#test").load("file.php"); });, I get ReferenceError: $ is not defined <anonymous>.

Comment: Check now. I missed a bracket.

Comment: Still "$ is not defined".

Comment: Is it wordpress? Have you loaded jQuery properly?

Comment: Yup Agreed with @GonrasKarols. First check that JQuery loaded. Add alerts just after $(document)... line

Comment: Like I said, I'm brand new to AJAX. I didn't know I had to load JQuery. Everything is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to specify file.php's whole address in your ajax call like this -

```
$("#test").click(function(){
$("#test").load('url to home.php');
});
```

If that won't solve the case, you should log a bit more of your ajax response and you'll be able to easily observe and solve it by yourself, like this:

```
$("#test").load("home.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
   if (status == "error") {
    console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
   }
});
```

Check your console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected your code. You don't need a Event listener, cause you already use `onclick="changeText3()"`

```
function changeText3(){
  $("#test").load("test.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
     console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: I get "$ is not defined: changeText3, onclick".